# How to use MemoryStream Instead of FileStream

Tags: c#

I currently write a file to the file system and then use FileStream to offer it up as a download to a user. However, there is no need for this extra step of Document In Memory to File System to Stream. I should just go from Document In Memory to Stream. I am having a heck of a time, though figuring out how to do this.

Right now I am using this:

```
Stream dl = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

But how to do I get `Stream dl` from the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document caf_doc` that I have in memory. I think I need to use MemoryStream.

The trouble I am having is getting the document into the MemoryStream.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code where you _save_ the file to the file system?

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: The trouble I am having is getting the document into the MemoryStream. (I've updated my question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a memory stream and save the document to it. Then reset the position of the memory stream, and you can read from it:

```
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()) {
  caf_doc.Save(m);
  m.Position = 0;
  // here you can read from the stream m
}
```

Comment: This didn't fix my problem but I think it answers my question above. I think I need to create a new question and state it differently.

Comment: @Eric: What further problem do you have then? This gives you a stream just as when you read it from a file, what more do you need?

Comment: I happened to see a new post by the OP which he subsequently deleted.  I think he may want to know how to write it to the Http Response Stream i.e. `caf_doc.Save(Response.Output);`